# Negative lookahead regex up till numbers but no consecutive 0s

Tags: java, regex

I'm extracting a string up to a series of 3-6 numbers. However I do not want to include a number with more then 3 consecutive 0's.

What I've got right now is a regular lookahead, however how do i implement the zero part?

```
(\d{3,6})[:|\s]{0,2}([a-zA-Z]{3})((?:(?!\d{3,6}).)*)
```

Example input:

```
010113 tee Some text for a 1000 reasons 020113 mee More text
```

So the input is in the format `[3-6 numbers] [3 letter identifier] [message]` (repeat)

I need it to match the string up until `020113`, not just until `1000`.

Comment: What should be the result for a string that contains a number of *more* than 6 digits? Ignore that too?

Comment: That string starts with 6 digits already, why not stop before those?

Comment: Because I need that bit, the six digits here are dates, but they can be anything from 3-6 digits as a date. I need to split up the string in substrings running from date to date. Now it stops at 1000 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest lookahead assertions:

```
((?:(?!(?!\d*000)\d{3,6}).)*)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(             # Match/capture in group 1:
 (?:          # Start of non-capturing group.
  (?!         # Assert that it's impossible to match...
   (?!\d*000) # (unless it's a number that contains 000)
   \d{3,6}    # a number of three to six digits here.
  )           # End of lookahead
  .           # Match any character
 )*           # End of non-capturing group, repeat any number of times
)             # End of capturing group 1
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bB8kL6).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the detailed explanation and for pointing me to that helpful site.